# Open three tabs of accordion panel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an accordion panel with 5 tabs Namely Department Name, student Name, serial number, age and comments.In each tab, I have prime faces text area to enter. After entering all details I am saving it. Now I will try to edit this information. While editing information I want the accordion panel implementation as below,

1. When I click on edit how to make `p:inputTextarea` enable so that it can be edited. Currently tab is high lighted not the `p:inputTextarea`.
2. when any information is edited, respective tab should be highlighted after saving. For example age and comments are edited, I have to highlight two tabs after saving, so that user can understand that age and comments has been edited. setting Active index opens only one tab. setting **mutiple** to true opens all the tabs. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

use the binding attribute of the accordian panel. when you save data, decide which tab need to be highlighted. In backing bean set the active tab accordingly.

Example:

**In your view:**

```
<p:accordionPanel autoHeight="false"  binding="#{mybackingbean.panel}"  ....other attributes you need... />
```

**in backing bean:**

```
@ManagedBean(name="mybackingbean")
public class MyBackingBean
{
    private AccordionPanel panel;

    //Setter and getter for panel

    public String saveAction() 
    {
        if(somecondition)
        {
            panel.setActiveIndex(1);
        }
        else
        {
            panel.setActiveIndex(0);
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to to do some thing like this:

public String saveAction() 
    {
        if(somecondition)
        {
            panel.setActiveIndex(1);
            panel.setActiveIndex(0);
            panel.setActiveIndex(2);
        }
        
        return "";
    }
}

Comment: I think accordian panel gives focus to **one** tab at a time.

Comment: yes I agree with you,but I wanted to know is there any work around so that It can be implemented..

Comment: use p:panel with a closable attribute, see: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel.jsf